# AMD ATI RADEON Three monitor issue

Tags: multiple-monitors, amd-radeon

Here is my issue,  I have an ATI Radeon 5850 Video Card.  I want to run three monitors, Currently I have tried using two DVI ports plus the Display Port (DP) with an HDMI adapter. The adapter is a Rocketfish RF-DP49402.  I have tried ever possible combination to get this to work.  HDMI to DVI cable with a DVI to DVI and and a straight HDMI cable, Two Standard DVI cables and a HDMI cable, two DVIs with the DP to HDMI adapter.  I am pulling my hair out trying to figure this out can some one please tell me what I am doing wrong.  By the way when I disconnect one of the monitors the one that isn't working starts working.  Its driving me crazy.  Please help me out. Thanks.

Specs,
AMD ATI Radeon 5850
AMD Phenom 2 965 Black
Asus Evo Motherboard
1TB Hard drive

Comment: Which one doesn't work?

Comment: it depends, if I unplug the DP then the two DVIs work if I plug it back in, the bottom DVI turns off.  I unplug the top DVI the bottom DVI and the DP work, and if I unplug the the top only the bottom DVI works.  ITs so weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess your passive DP-HDMI adapter is the culprit.

I couldn't find AMD's webpage that described Eyefinity in details, but some remnants of its contents are still online on [Sapphire website](http://www.sapphiretech.com/eyefinity/eyefinity_about.html):

> It’s important to remember that it’s not just the form factor (physical shape) of the DisplayPort (DP) and DVI connectors that are different, the electrical display signal is very different as well. Passive adapters contain nothing but connectors and cables. They do not change the electrical format of the signal in any way. (…)
>
> In the case of Eyefinity across three monitors, all of the possible DVI signals are used up on the other two DVI or HDMI (HDMI video signals are the same as DVI signals) outputs so the board can only output a DP signal from the DP connector. Passing this signal to a DVI monitor (by using a passive adapter) will not work as the DVI monitor will not be able to interpret and decode the DP signal to create a picture.

It may not be clear from this excerpt, but Eyefinity supports up to 2 DVI or HDMI monitors and the rest has to be connected with DisplayPort or through active adapters. I guess this is a hardware limitation and it applies to non-Eyefinity setup too.

Comment: Thank you so much, that makes sense.  I couldn't understand all the jargon on the forums.  I appreciate it.  Now to find an active adapter.